Значение primery key из таблицы = 0
Изучаю hibernate по курсу Трегулова. Ссылка на видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQOfeJT7KCY&list=PLqj7-hRTFl_p-t5F2zSUlG6_9UIoE2r70&index=44, тайминг: 4 мин +-.
У меня из переменной "myID" всегда возвращается 0. Не знаю, что делать. Мне нужно чтобы в переменную возвращалось значение id из таблицы.
Вот код:

Вот сущность:

Вот таблица:


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

В подсвеченном коде в строке 29 у вас Entity не из БД, а из new Employee. Он будет всегда 0, так как у вас примитивный тип int и он имеет дефолтное значение 0.
Если вы его поменяете на Integer, то тут будете получать null, что более корректнее.
Ну а что бы решить вашу проблему в строке 25 получите значение из бд
employee2 = session.save(employee2)

